# How to capture SKNode with transparent background?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, uiimage, skspritenode

Right now I captured with this code:

```
    CGRect bounds = self.scene.view.bounds;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage* screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This captures the whole scene. It works well, but what I want is just capturing a single SKNode only that was put in the scene, with transparent background. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I tried

```
self.scene.view.allowsTransparency = YES;
self.scene.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.scene.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But didn't work either. Meh.

Comment: [`[SKView textureFromNode:node]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520114-texturefromnode?language=objc) -> `SKTexture` -> underlying image via the [`CGImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktexture/1519755-cgimage?language=objc) method -> [`[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624126-imagewithcgimage?language=objc) - does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

in your scene add the below implementation of touches to your scene and add the correct node in place of the XXXXX.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let test = view?.texture(from: XXXXX)
    let testSpriteFromTexture = SKSpriteNode(texture: test)
    testSpriteFromTexture.position = XXXXX.position
    let testImage = test?.cgImage()
    XXXXX.removeFromParent()
    addChild(testSpriteFromTexture)
}
```

To note if you are capturing dynamic content, where the SKNode you are capturing has a changing frame size. Then you may run into an issue when trying to centre the new node or image

Hope this works